# Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account on listing Config pda address in auctioneer sale in auctionhouse

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm trying to use auctioneer sale function from the auctioneer sdk. But i get this Error

`'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh invoke [1]', 'Program log: Instruction: Sell', "4xd58eAU6pZQCwSigE5bXMspTKus1fBFm1TpDU4m4AWc's signer privilege escalated", 'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh consumed 15605 of 200000 compute units', 'Program neer8g6yJq2mQM6KbnViEDAD4gr3gRZyMMf4F2p3MEh failed: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account'`

The Address `4xd58eAU6pZQCwSigE5bXMspTKus1fBFm1TpDU4m4AWc` is the address of the listing config address.

I'm Finding auctioneer with this

```
 const listingConfig = await PublicKey.createProgramAddress(
      [ Buffer.from("listing_config"),
      publicKey.toBuffer(),
      aH.toBuffer(),
      associatedAddress.toBuffer(),
      WRAPPED_SOL_MINT.toBuffer(),
      mint.toBuffer(),
      new BN(1)
    ],
    AUCTIONEER
  )
```

which is the same as defined in this

```
pub fn find_listing_config_address(
    wallet: &Pubkey,
    auction_house: &Pubkey,
    token_account: &Pubkey,
    treasury_mint: &Pubkey,
    token_mint: &Pubkey,
    token_size: u64,
) -> (Pubkey, u8) {
    Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[
            LISTING_CONFIG.as_bytes(),
            wallet.as_ref(),
            auction_house.as_ref(),
            token_account.as_ref(),
            treasury_mint.as_ref(),
            token_mint.as_ref(),
            &token_size.to_le_bytes(),
        ],
        &id(),
    )
}
```

could it be possible that the error is coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

In the listing Config we have to pass token size to a buffer like

```
const listingConfig = await PublicKey.createProgramAddress(
      [ Buffer.from("listing_config"),
      publicKey.toBuffer(),
      aH.toBuffer(),
      associatedAddress.toBuffer(),
      WRAPPED_SOL_MINT.toBuffer(),
      mint.toBuffer(),
      new BN (1).toBuffer('le',8)
    ],
    AUCTIONEER
  )
```